# Need to access iis virtual directory using python script

Tags: python, iis, virtual-directory

I need to access iis virtual directory created for my we app using python. Is it possible using python?

Comment: Does anyone know the python code to access virtual directory of iis

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to set correct permission to application pool which python use.

Set the identity of application pool which python application use to local system or custom account(the account should have enough permission to read folder in machine).
[image]

Set the permissions of the physical folder corresponding to the virtual directory. Right click and select Security, Edit, Add. Type in application pool's name.
[image]

Click OK. Then check the permission for application pool.
[image]

Comment: Thanks.. Do you know the python code to access virtual directory of iis

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in python and do not know the relevant code.